# Capybara + Unable to set cookie while execution of automation script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cookies, automated-tests, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

```
browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
browser.manage.add_cookie :name => "introduction_done", :value => "yes"
#even tired this one as well
browser.manage.add_cookie name: "introduction_done", value: "yes"
```

Got the Error

```
# --- Caused by: ---
# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchCollectionError:
# unable to set cookie
# (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
# (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64)
# /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.13.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set the cookie before visiting any URL.
As explained on [this article on jamescroft.com](https://www.jamesrcroft.com/2018/02/selenium-webdriver-error-nosuchcollectionerror/) and this [Selenium issue on GitHub](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2835), you need to do something like:

```
visit 'https://your_website.com'
browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
browser.manage.add_cookie :name => "introduction_done", :value => "yes"
```